# Moq for c# training not working on first test in suite

Tags: c#, moq

I'm new to c# as well and the Moq framework. I'm using VS 2010 express and NUnit

In my [Setup] function, I have:

```
    this.mockAllianceController = new Mock<AllianceController>();
    this.mockAllianceController.Setup(ac => ac.getAllies(this.currentRealm)).Returns(new List<string>());

    ...

    this.testObj = new DiplomacyLogic(this.mockAllianceController.Object);
```

The first test in the suite gets a null returned, while each test after that gets the empty list. What am I missing?

**Update:**

Code under test:

```
    public void ApplyRelations() {
        List<string> allies = this.AllianceController.getAllies(this.RealmName);
        foreach (string ally in allies) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public virtual List<string> getAllies(string realm) {
        ...
    }
```

Two test cases:

```
    [Test]
    public void aTest() {
        this.testObj.ApplyRelations();
    }

    [Test]
    public void bTest() {
        this.testObj.ApplyRelations();
    }
```

aTest will throw a NullReferenceException while bTest passes fine. Any help?

Comment: Post the code for the first test.

Comment: I'm a doofus. I initialized this.currentRealm after the Setup. XD

So the real question isn't why did the first test fail, but why did the second test pass? I guess without a [TearDown], this.currentRealm didn't get destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you also show the declaration of `getAllies` and what `this.currentRealm` is.

But you probably want to change the line:

```
this.mockAllianceController.Setup(ac => ac.getAllies(this.currentRealm)).Returns(new List<string>());
```

into this:

```
this.mockAllianceController.Setup(ac => ac.getAllies(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new List<string>());
```

Note the `It.IsAny<string>()` as parameter for `getAllies()`.

Comment: currentRealm is just a string.

I want the function to return null when called with anything other than the string I specify in the test case.

Comment: @Shane - Wimmel's on the right track. In your case I would pass in a constant to the getAllies method in the Setup. That way it doesn't matter when you initialize currentRealm. And yes, you could be sharing state between test methods (bad). Reinitialize everything in Setup, reset any fields/globals in TearDown, or just use local variables (possibly created with test factory methods) in your test methods.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905406/does-nunit-create-a-new-instance-of-the-test-fixture-class-for-each-contained-tes

Answer (score 0):

If `AllianceController` is a class and not an interface, you may want to do:

```
this.mockAllianceController = new Mock<AllianceController>();
this.mockAllianceController.CallBase = True
```

this means that you create a Mock object that will wrap an existing object and map all method calls to the original object by default (unless an explicit `Setup` has been called)

(see http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Customizing_Mock_Behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I think your setups is done in the wrong order and this causes the setup not to be valid in the first testrun and then in the second testrun the `this.testObj = new DiplomacyLogic(this.mockAllianceController.Object);` is already created and the setup is initilazed. This means you should initialize the `DiplomacyLogic` before the setup to get your desired result.

I also included a teardown code so you get fresh objects for each test, this is good practice so that tests are not dependent on eachother.

try the code below.

```
[Setup]   
public void Setup()
{
    this.mockAllianceController = new Mock<AllianceController>();
    this.testObj = new DiplomacyLogic(this.mockAllianceController.Object);

    this.mockAllianceController.Setup(ac => ac.getAllies(this.currentRealm)).Returns(new         List<string>());
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    this.mockAllianceController = null;
    this.testObj = null;
}
```

I also think that the setup code should be in the testmethod insteed of setup and that is becasuse of other tests you might write will maby not use the same setup for just that method.