# Running all tests in parallel fails with invalid session id

Tags: c#, selenium

I have 4 tests in a test class, when I run each separately they pass. However, when I run them all in parallel, they fail. I believe the issue is with tests using the same Driver instance. I've changed the driver to be protected, but the result is the same. Parallel tests are failing.

**WebDriver class:**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace TestAutomationFramework.Utilities
{
    public class WebDriver
    {
        protected IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**TestSetup class:**

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using TestAutomationFramework.Utilities;

namespace TestAutomationFramework.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestSetup : WebDriver
    {
        public TestSetup()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        // Test Setup, every test starts with this method
        [SetUp]
        public void StartTest()
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        }

        // Test Tear Down, every test ends with this method
        [TearDown]
        public void QuitTest()
        {
            Driver.Close();
            Driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**BasePage class:**

```
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace TestAutomationFramework.Pages
{
    public class BasePage
    {
        protected IWebDriver WebDriver;
        public BasePage(IWebDriver webDriver) => WebDriver = webDriver;

        #region Elements
        private IWebElement SearchField => WebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        private IWebElement SearchButton => WebDriver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"));

        #endregion

        public void SearchFor(string searchText)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(2000);
            SearchField.SendKeys(searchText);
            SearchButton.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        public bool SearchResultShows(string whatShows)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            var element = WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(
                "//*[@id='rhs_block']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span"));
            return element.Text.Equals(whatShows);
        }
    }
}
```

**DemoTest class**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using TestAutomationFramework.Pages;

namespace TestAutomationFramework.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
    public class DemoTest : TestSetup
    {
        private BasePage _basePage;

        [Test]
        public void TestLogin()
        {
            const string query = "Test automation";
            _basePage = new BasePage(webDriver: Driver);
            _basePage.SearchFor(query);
            var shows = _basePage.SearchResultShows(whatShows: query);
            Assert.IsTrue(shows);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestLogin2()
        {
            const string query = "Test automation";
            _basePage = new BasePage(webDriver: Driver);
            _basePage.SearchFor(query);
            var shows = _basePage.SearchResultShows(whatShows: query);
            Assert.IsTrue(shows);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestLogin3()
        {
            const string query = "Test automation";
            _basePage = new BasePage(webDriver: Driver);
            _basePage.SearchFor(query);
            var shows = _basePage.SearchResultShows(whatShows: query);
            Assert.IsTrue(shows);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestLogin4()
        {
            const string query = "Test automation";
            _basePage = new BasePage(webDriver: Driver);
            _basePage.SearchFor(query);
            var shows = _basePage.SearchResultShows(whatShows: query);
            Assert.IsTrue(shows);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to solve the driver instance so all tests don't use the same driver?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Does NUnit create a new instance of the test fixture class for each contained test method nowadays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905406/does-nunit-create-a-new-instance-of-the-test-fixture-class-for-each-contained-te) the test class instance is the same for all tests. The `Driver` instance is destroyed as soon as the first test runs (in method `QuitTest`) so the other test won't have a driver anymore.

Try this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestSetup
{
   private ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> _driver;

   protected IWebDriver Driver => _driver.Value;

   // Test Setup, every test starts with this method
   [SetUp]
   public void StartTest()        
   {
       var options = new ChromeOptions();
       _driver = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>(() => new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
       Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
       Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
   }

   // Test Tear Down, every test ends with this method
   [TearDown]
   public void QuitTest()
   {
       Driver.Close();
       Driver.Quit();
       _driver.Dispose();
   }
}
```

This may impact performance because of `TheadLocal`. I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution works, but as you've said I am looking for parallel execution. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Silly me... I thought xUnit can run tests in the same class in parallel. It can not. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a dictionary with drivers where key is thread id and value is driver used by test.

```
private static Dictionary<int, IWebDriver> drivers = new Dictionary<int, IWebDriver();

public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
{
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    if (!drivers.Keys.Contains(id))
    {
        SetupNewDriver();
    }
    return drivers[id];
}
```

While creating driver you add it to dictionary (below line is from SetupDriver method):

```
drivers.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, driver);
```

In my project I have created class DriverManager with above code and it works. Minus is that you won't be able to run multiple drivers for one test. There is possibility to make more complicated structure for drivers, but I didn't have a need for that.